# How to mount microphone and recorder on the DSLR?

Tags: dslr, microphone

I keep reading that for proper sound you should use an external recorder like the Zoom H1 or H4N with your DSLR. Until now, I was only using an external microphone, namely the Takstar SGC-598, without an extra recorder.

**My question is, how do you mount both the mic and the recorder on the DSLR which has only one hot shoe.**

Recently, I've been shooting my first documentary video, holding the camera just like that with no steadycam, shoulder rig etc. Also, I was on my own so there was nobody to hold the microphone (and potentially a recorder) separately. Therefore I had to attach it directly to the camera.
Having only the camera with little extra gear made the shooting very dynamic which I liked.

I looked at a few Hot Shoe Y-Adapters but none really convinced me.

Do you have any experience with a setup like this? How do you mount mic and recorder on the camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple answers.

The easiest and cheaper solution is to get a shoe extender.

The more professional way is to get an external recorder specifically designed for DSLR mounting. Look at the products of BeachTek and JuiceLink for examples.